# How to assign null value to CharSequence in java?

Tags: java, android, null, charsequence

In my app I was using  EditText. I would like to assign numberOfYearsBirthday=0 when there is no text in the edittext.

I have tried the following code and debugged. I have seen that even if my charSequence="" but it ignore the statement and move to the else statement and thus cause error and crash my app assigning null value as an integer.

```
xB1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int before, int count) {                                        

        if(String.valueOf(charSequence)==null){
            numberOfYearsBirthday=0;
        }else{numberOfYearsBirthday= Integer.valueOf(charSequence.toString());
        }
```

I have also tried the following code

```
charSequence.toString()==""
```

Moreover, the following one too

```
charSequence ==""
```

but the program is overlooking my if statement. What's the wrong I am doing here?

Comment: `if( charSequence == null || charSequence.length() == 0 ){..}`

Comment: Why do I need to use "charSequence == null" ?

Comment: Because according to you question it can be possible that `charSequence` will be null too.

Comment: `String.valueOf()` doesn't return null. If you want to check `charSequence` for null, *compare* it to null, with the `==` operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `charSequence` is null, then using [`String::valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf-java.lang.Object-) will return the text "null" which is different to a `null` reference and hence your condition won't work. Also doing `charSequence.toString()==""` won't work because this is not the proper way to [compare Strings in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java).

Try this instead:

```
// check if charSequence is null or empty ""
if (charSequence == null || charSequence.toString().isEmpty()) {
    numberOfYearsBirthday = 0;
} else {
    numberOfYearsBirthday = Integer.valueOf(charSequence.toString());
}
```

Comment: I have got it. But one more thing. 
if (charSequence.toString().isEmpty())   --is working fine. What's the benefit of using "charSequence == null" ?

Comment: if `charSequence` is null and you do `charSequence.toString().isEmpty()` then you would get a [`NullPointerException`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it).

Answer (score 0):

use `TextUtils.isEmpty(charSequence)`.

Your error for the first solution only checks for `null` which is not the same as an empty String.

The second one does not work because the correct way to check Strings for value equality in Java is `stringValue.equals("")`. `==` will check if the two Strings are the same instance of the String, which they aren't.